# Npgsql with linq expression to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, linq-to-entities

I develop windows service, which is connected to public web.service and incrementally download data to own database. This same service is for two customers. One of them have a MS SQL Server 2012 and the second have Postgres server.

I created database structure (tables, indexes, foreign keys) for both database. Then a was creating Entity Framework DBContext.

In some cases I need to check, if record exists in Database like this:

```
public virtual Boolean ExistsRecordType(String recordType, Boolean isCaseSensitive = false)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recordType))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("recordType");

   if (isCaseSensitive)
   {
       return this.DBContext.RecordTypes.Any(a => a.Type == recordType);
   }
   else
   {
       return this.DBContext.RecordTypes.Any(a => a.Type.ToUpper() == recordType.ToUpper());
   }
}
```

MSSQL server is OK, but on Postregress I get this exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException in assembly EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

and Inner exception is:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException
ERROR: 42703: column "etrue" does not exist
```

but in my models does not exists a column with name **etrue**.

In project i use this nuget packages:

```
Npgsql.EF6, version 2.0.12-pre4(Prerelease)
Npgsql, version 2.0.14.3
EntityFramework, version 6.0.2
```

My config file for MSSQL is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBContext" connectionString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <!-- PostgreSql -->
      <remove invariant="Npgsql"></remove>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
        invariant="Npgsql"
        description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
        type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

And a config file for Postress is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=user;Password=pass;Database=MyDB;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20;
ConnectionLifeTime=15;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <!-- PostgreSql -->
      <remove invariant="Npgsql"></remove>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
        invariant="Npgsql"
        description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
        type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Does anyone where is the problem?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I was able to catch a generated query to DB a looks like this:

```
SELECT  
CASE  WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS "C1" FROM "dbo"."recordtype" AS "Extent1" 
                    WHERE (((upper("Extent1"."Type")) = (upper(((E'5'))))) AND ( NOT ((upper("Extent1"."Type") IS NULL ) 
                          OR (upper(((E'5'))) IS NULL )))) OR ((upper("Extent1"."Type") IS NULL ) AND (upper(((E'5'))) IS NULL )))) THEN (ETRUE) 
       WHEN (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS "C1" FROM "dbo"."recordtype" AS "Extent2" 
                         WHERE (((upper("Extent2"."Type")) = (upper(((E'5'))))) AND ( NOT ((upper("Extent2"."Type") IS NULL ) 
                         OR (upper(((E'5'))) IS NULL )))) OR ((upper("Extent2"."Type") IS NULL ) AND (upper(((E'5'))) IS NULL )))) THEN (EFALSE) END  AS "C1" 
FROM (SELECT 1 AS "C") AS "SingleRowTable1"
```

The problem is here, but right now a don't know how to fix it.
Is a bug in npgsql library or problem is on my site?

**UPDATE2**

This a bug in npgsql and someone report it on http://pgfoundry.org/tracker/?group_id=1000140&atid=590&func=detail&aid=1011388

Comment: What's the actual SQL that gets run? You can get it from nPgSQL's logs, or from PostgreSQL's logs if you enable `log_statement = 'all'` and reload the service.

Comment: I was updating query - look at this now. Problem is not in version of servers or on server site, but in linq, probably.

Comment: Wow, so it's actually emitting a literal `EFALSE`. Wonder if that's supposed to be `E'FALSE'` and being mangled? Suspect you're going to need some quality debugger time on this one to find out what's responsible by tracing the layers. Though enabling query logging in LINQ / Entity Framework may be informative.

Comment: I thing, that this is a bug in npgsql.dll. because on MSSQL server its working good. And in fact, it should be E'FALSE' and E'TRUE'... but right now i need resolved it - i cannot rewriting many classes through the Where extensions, which works on both servers

Comment: It could well be Entity Framework's PostgreSQL dialect too. You'll need to trace it in enough detail to isolate the fault so you can report a bug to the right place.

Comment: This is a reported bug in npgsql :-(